# doctors appointments or doctor's appointments or doctors' appointments

Tags: grammatical-number

["Doctor's appointment" or "doctors appointment"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24158/doctors-appointment-or-doctors-appointment)

Not sure this was properly addressed before but question was where to put the "'" on the s.

In the question it was about having multiple appointments that day, each appointment with a different doctor. So when you state you have multiple appointments that day with different doctors what should it be?

My guess is i have doctors appointments. Is that right?

Comment: If the doctors are  plural then "doctors' appointments" is correct, however it doesn't make the plurality of the doctors clear in speech. The clearest forms to use are "I've got an appointment with the doctors today" if you have one appointment with more than one doctor or "I've got appointments with several doctors today" if you have several appointments each with a different doctor.

Comment: so when you say to make plurality clear you say "i've got an appointment with the doctors today", so how about this "I've got appointments with doctors today"?